# JQuery click() event listener not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, events

im trying to get a lil project going but im stuck on a very annoying thing.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#search-button").click(console.log('hello'))
});
```

as you can see im targeting a search button with the id `search-button` and as soon as i click it something should happen. in this case i put a console.log in to test if it works but it doesn't. it always logs it as soon as i load the page , not when i click the button i target.  ... what am i doing wrong
if you need more info on this pls tell me i tried to keep it as simple as i could

ty for your help

O.k

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The click handler needs a function argument, not just the console.log by itself. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#search-button").click(function() {
      console.log('hello');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside of `.click` should be a handler `.click(handler)` and the handler should be a function. The browser is reading the code and when it hits `console.log('hello')`, it does it! It's seeing `.click` etc, but it doesn't matter; it next sees `console.log` and does it.

Try

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#search-button").click(function() {
    console.log('hello');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, the click function requires its own callback function. You can also use this, without requiring the use of *document*:

```
$("#search-button").on('click', function() {
    console.log('hello')
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope You're using jQuery version 3 or up. if you use 3 or up jquery version the good practice is you use Document binding Example:

```
jQuery(document).on('click', '#search-button', function(event) {
    //your Code here...
    console.log('hello');
 });
```

Comment: jQuery(document).on('event'... use for dynamically event binding. element. click event or normal click event work only when window load But you load dynamic document then use 'on' binding or document binding.